# Rails an MongoDB, how to get the last document inserted and be sure it is thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, thread-safety

I need when I add a new document in my collection X to get the last document that was inserted in that same collection, because some values of that document must influence the document I am currently inserting.

Basically as a simple example I would need to do that:

```
class X
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  before_save :set_sum

  def set_sum
   self.sum = X.last.sum + self.misc
  end

  field :sum, :type => Integer

  field :misc, :type => Integer
end
```

How can I make sure that type of process will never break if there are concurrent insert? I must make sure that when `self.sum = X.last.sum + self.misc` is calculate that `X.last.sum` absolutely represents that last possible document inserted in the collection ?

This is critical to my system. It needs to be thread safe.

Alex

ps: this also needs to be performant, when there are 50k documents in the collections, it can't take time to get the last value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this kind of behavior is equivalent to having an auto increment id.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How+to+Make+an+Auto+Incrementing+Field
The cleanest way is to have a side collection with one (or more) docs representing the current total values.
Then in your client, before inserting the new doc, do a findAndModify() that atomically updates the totals AND retrieves the current total doc.
Part of the current doc can be an auto increment _id, so that even if there are concurrent inserts, your document will then be correctly ordered as long as you sort by _id.
Only caveat: if your client app dies after findAndModify and before insert, you will have a gap in there.
Either that's ok or you need to add extra protections like keeping a side log.

If you want to be 100% safe you can also get inspiration from 2-phase commit
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/two-phase+commit
Basically it is the proper way to do transaction with any db that spans more than 1 server (even sql wouldnt help there)
best
AG

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep a running sum, this should probably be done on another document in a different collection.  The best way to keep this running sum is to use the `$inc` atomic operation.  There's really no need to perform any reads while calculating this sum.

You'll want to insert your X document into its collection, then also `$inc` a value on a different document that is meant for keeping this tally of all the `misc` values from the X documents.

Note: This still won't be transactional, because you're updating two documents in two different collections separately, but it will be highly performant, and fully thread safe.

Fore more info, check out all the [MongoDB Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations).

Comment: well the issue, is that the calculation operations I need to perform involves things a wee bit more complex than simple sum calculation (therefore I cannot use $inc) and I need to do it on 5 or 6 fields?